# Props no funcionan en Laravel con vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

estoy teniendo problemas para llevar mi proyecto de laravel a produccion...
pues tengo incovenientes con las rutas por lo cual estoy queriendo usar un props

mi app.js

```
    const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data :{
        menu : 0,
        notifications: [],
        ruta: 'http://localhost:80/sistema/public'
    },
    created() {
        let me = this;     
        axios.post('notification/get').then(function(response) {
           //console.log(response.data);
           me.notifications=response.data;    
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

        var userId = $('meta[name="userId"]').attr('content');

        Echo.private('App.User.' + userId).notification((notification) => {
             me.notifications.unshift(notification); 
        }); 

    }        
});
```

despues lo que hago es pasarle mi propiedad ruta al componente

```
<template v-if="menu==0">
            <dashboard :ruta="ruta"></dashboard>
        </template>
```

y asi lo quiero usar el el componente

```
export default {
    props: ['ruta'],
    data (){
        return {
            varIngreso:null,
            charIngreso:null,
            ingresos:[],
            varTotalIngreso:[],
            varMesIngreso:[], 

            varVenta:null,
            charVenta:null,
            ventas:[],
            varTotalVenta:[],
        }
    },
    methods : {
        getIngresos(){
            let me=this;
            var url= this.ruta + '/dashboard';
            axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
                var respuesta= response.data;
                me.ingresos = respuesta.ingresos;
                //cargamos los datos del chart
                me.loadIngresos();
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
```

No se que estoy haciendo mal o que estoy pasando por alto pero en la consola me sale este error

Property or method "ruta" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property

Comment: De principio todo se ve bien.  Pero en el componente de abajo estas usando vue-cli y en el de arriba no? Si no usas `data` como metodo tal vez no te lo reconoce.

Comment: Utiliza interceptores en Axios para que no tengas que estar pasando siempre la ruta base.

Comment: El problema fue `ruta: 'http://localhost:80/sistema/public'` en mi app.js, lo cambie por la ip de la pc y funciono.... No tengo idea de porque paso eso